# How to render Latex markup using Python?

Tags: python, latex, formula

How to show an easy latex-formula in python?
Maybe numpy is the right choice?

I have python code like:

```
a = '\frac{a}{b}'
```

and want to print this in a graphical output (like matplotlib).

Comment: What do you mean 'show latex formula in python'. Do you want to extract a formula from a .tex file and print it to python's stdout, implement a formula shown in a a .tex (pdf/ps) file in python or what?

Comment: Can you clarify? Where do you want to print it? Do you want to generate images or are you looking for something inside a gui?

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. :/ Please see the edit.

Comment: See the docs on the matplotlib site: - [Text rendering With LaTeX](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically generate markdown output in Jupyter notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks)

Comment: This question has a much easier-to-use answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313217/6651650

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As suggested by Andrew little work around using matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = '\\frac{a}{b}'  #notice escaped slash
plt.plot()
plt.text(0.5, 0.5,'$%s$'%a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can someone explain line 3 to me? Is the semi-colon just a typo?

Comment: @Annan The semicolon is just separates two lines. You may just as well put `plt.text(0.5,0.5,'$%s$'%a)` on a new line.

Answer (score 20):

An answer based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313217/2641825) specific to Jupyter notebook, using f-string to format an `$x_i$` variable:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Latex
for i in range(3):
    display(Latex(f'$x_{i}$'))
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

**Note:** The [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (formatted string literal) uses curly braces to insert the value of the Python variable `i`. You’ll need to [double the curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/2641825) (`f'{{}}'`) to actually use `{}` in the LaTeX code. Otherwise, you can use single curly braces directly in a normal Python string (not an f-string).

**Side Note:** I'm surprised Stack Overflow still [doesn’t have a math markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: In my opinion, this should be the answer. Clear and concise

Comment: On my end it shows "<IPython.core.display.Latex object>". Is that a bug or am I missing to enable something. (I'm on MacOS)

Comment: @Shaheerziya maybe because you are not inside a jupyter notebook or lab? Are you executing the code at a python prompt or inside a notebook?

Answer (score 8):

Creating mathematical formulas in Pandas.

```
a = r'\frac{a}{b}'
ax = plt.axes([0,0,0.3,0.3]) #left,bottom,width,height
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.axis('off')
plt.text(0.4,0.4,'$%s$' %a,size=50,color="green")
```

[image]

```
a = r'f(x) = \frac{\exp(-x^2/2)}{\sqrt{2*\pi}}'
ax = plt.axes([0,0,0.3,0.3]) #left,bottom,width,height
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.axis('off')
plt.text(0.4,0.4,'$%s$' %a,size=50,color="green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib can already do TeX, by setting `text.usetex: True` in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. Then, you can just use TeX in all displayed strings, e.g.,

```
ylabel(r"Temperature (K) [fixed $\beta=2$]")
```

(be sure to use the `$` as in normal in-line TeX!). The `r` before the string means that no substitutions are made; otherwise you have to escape the slashes as mentioned.

More info at the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) site.

Comment: Is matplotlibrc in the matplotlib-folder? I cant find it :/

Comment: On UNIX systems, it's in the directory I mention above. On windows, I don't know. Check the Docs.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12 and installed matplotlib in the system (not user), in my case its on /etc/matplotlibrc

Comment: Is that option really necessary? [The documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) states that's if you want to use an actual LaTeX installation for advanced features, while TeX-math rendering is [natively supported](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

Without ticks:

```
a = r'\frac{a}{b}'
ax = plt.axes([0,0,0.1,0.2]) #left,bottom,width,height
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.text(0.3,0.4,'$%s$' %a,size=40)
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw with matplotlib,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = r'\frac{a}{b}'
ax=plt.subplot(111)
ax.text(0.5,0.5,r"$%s$" %(a),fontsize=30,color="green")
plt.show()
```

---

[image]