# How can I print a string using .format(), and print literal curly brackets around my replaced string

Tags: python, string, formatting, string-formatting, curly-brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I print a literal “{}” characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

Basically, I want to use .format(), like this:

```
my_string = '{{0}:{1}}'.format('hello', 'bonjour')
```

And have it match:

```
my_string = '{hello:bonjour}' #this is a string with literal curly brackets
```

However, the first piece of code gives me an error.

The curly brackets are important, because I'm using Python to communicate with a piece of software via text-based commands. I have no control over what kind of formatting the fosoftware expects, so it's crucial that I sort out all the formatting on my end. It uses curly brackets around strings to ensure that spaces in the strings are interpreted as single strings, rather than multiple arguments — much like you normally do with quotation marks in file paths, for example.

I'm currently using the older method:

```
my_string = '{%s:%s}' % ('hello', 'bonjour')
```

Which certainly works, but .format() seems easier to read, and when I'm sending commands with five or more variables all in one string, then readability becomes a significant issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Use "{{{0}:{1}}}" (double {{) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format

Comment: Yep, duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 29):

Here is the new style:

```
>>> '{{{0}:{1}}}'.format('hello', 'bonjour')
'{hello:bonjour}'
```

But I thinking escaping is somewhat hard to read, so I prefer to switch back to the older style to avoid escaping:

```
>>> '{%s:%s}' % ('hello', 'bonjour')
'{hello:bonjour}'
```