# Using quote-like-operators or quotes in the perl's printf

Tags: perl

Reading perl sources I saw many times the next construction:

```
printf qq[%s\n], getsomestring( $_ );
```

But *usually* it is written as

```
printf "%s\n", getsomestring( $_ );
```

The question:

- is here any "good practice" what is the correct way, and if yes
- when is recommended to use the longer `qq[...]` vs the `"..."`
- or it is only pure TIMTOWTDI?

The [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: I like to think of `"..."`, `'...'`, and `\`...\`` as shortcuts for `qq"..."`, `q'...'`, and `qx\`...\``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `qq()` as an alternative double quote method, such as when you have double quotes in the string. For example:

```
"\"foo bar\""
```

Looks better when written

```
qq("foo bar")
```

When in the windows cmd shell, which uses double quotes, I often use `qq()` when I need interpolation. For example:

```
perl -lwe "print qq($foo\n)"
```

The `qq()` operator -- like many other perl operators such as `s///`, `qx()` -- is also handy as you demonstrate because it can use just about any character as its delimiter:

```
qq[this works]
qq|as does this|
qq#or this#
```

This is handy for when you have many different delimiters in the string. For example:

```
qq!This is (not) "hard" to quote!
```

As for best practice, I would say use whatever is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I always use `qq[...]` when there are quotes in the strings, example:

```
qq["here you are", he said]
```

If not, for me is more readable the use of `""`