# Python use variable in f.write

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to use `f.write` i am not sure its a best way to do but i saw couple of example. here what i am trying to do, I have a file which contain following lines.

```
parallel (
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
                          build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "/path/to/build.xml", WARFILE: "http://www.example.com/repo/file.war", STUDY: "EXAMPLE", BUG: "007" )
}},
```

In above file you can see `BUILDFILE`, `WARFILE`, `STUDY` and `BUG` field. I want to to edit them using script in place of manually edit. I don't under stand how do i use variable in f.write() function. following what i am trying to do

```
BF = raw_input("Enter BUILDFILE name:")
WF = raw_input("Enter WARFILE name:")
STUDY = raw_input("Enter STUDY name:")
BUG = raw_input("Enter BUG name:")
f = open("myfile", "w")
data = """parallel (
    {
    ignore(FAILURE) {
                              build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "BF", WARFILE: "WF", STUDY: "STUDY", BUG: "BUG" )
    }},
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

when i am running this code it take my input and put in those specified field but some how its not working.. i don't know how to use f.write to take my variable and place in those fields. if there is a another way please let me know..

**EDIT**

I have modified script as per users suggested but still getting error, I am missing something ???

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

BF = raw_input("Enter BUILDFILE name:")
WF = raw_input("Enter WARFILE name:")
STUDY = raw_input("Enter STUDY name:")
BUG = raw_input("Enter BUG name:")
f = open("myfile", "w")

data = """parallel (
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
                          build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "{BF}", WARFILE: "{WF}", STUDY: "{STUDY}", BUG: "{BUG}" )
}},""".format(**locals())

f.write(data)
f.close()
```

following error i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sched.py", line 18, in <module>
    }},""".format(**locals())
KeyError: '\nignore(FAILURE) {\n                          build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE'
```

Comment: I guess you are missing the closing `"""` above

Comment: you need to double the `{` to escape them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try string formatting with the `str.format` method.  In this method, you can use a `{Name}` token in the string as a marker to be replaced.  Also note that you need to close you triple quoted string.

```
data = """parallel (
{{
ignore(FAILURE) {{
                          build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "{BF}", WARFILE: "{WF}", STUDY: "{STUDY}", BUG: "{BUG}" )
}}}},""".format(BUG=BUG,BF=BF,WF=WF,STUDY=STUDY)
```

Since you're also using literal `{` in your replacement string, [you need to double the `{` that you want to escape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

---

For the lazy,

```
data = """parallel (
{{
ignore(FAILURE) {{
                          build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "{BF}", WARFILE: "{WF}", STUDY: "{STUDY}", BUG: "{BUG}" )
}}}},""".format(**locals())
```

would also work but I wouldn't advise it as it isn't quite as clear.

Comment: I am getting this error: `File "./sched.py", line 13
    }},""".format(BUG=BUG,BF=BF,WF=WF,BUG=BUG)
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated`

Comment: @Satish remove the last `BUG=BUG`

Comment: Still i am getting error i guess i am missing some module, do you know which module i need to import for formate ?

Comment: Here is my error:: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sched.py", line 13, in <module>
    }},""".format(BF=BF,WF=WF,STUDY=STUDY,BUG=BUG)
KeyError: '\nignore(FAILURE) {\n      build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE'
`

Comment: @Satish -- Thanks.  It's hard to believe so many people upvoted a bad answer.  It turns out that you need to double the curly braces you aren't using to escape them.

Answer (score 2):

The `write`is not the problem here. You're not placing your variables in your data. (And you're not closing the string with `"""` either)

Try:

```
data = """parallel (
{{
    ignore(FAILURE) {{
      build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "{0}", WARFILE: "{1}", STUDY:"{2}", BUG: "{3}" )
}}}}
"""
f.write(data.format(BF, WF, STUDY, BUG))
```

Note that you have to quote the brackets by writing `{{` and `}}` (or python will complain, since it thinks it's the beginning of a format field)
And have a look at [Python's format function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

Comment: getting error at where `format` defined.. look like i need format module right?

Comment: No, you need to double the `{` and `}` if you want the to appear directly (my mistake). I updated the post.