# Key error when using the `str.format` function but not with %s syntax

Tags: python, string, format, string-formatting

Using python 2.7.4  and 3.3.1:

```
from textwrap import dedent as dd


name='Maruja'

print(dd('''
         {0}:
           _.-.
         '( ^{_}    (
           `~\`-----'\\
              )_)---)_)
         '''.format(name)))
```

It´s a key error in both:

```
$ python3 test.py    # or python2 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    '''.format(name)))
KeyError: '_'
```

With the % operator it works though:

```
from textwrap import dedent as dd


name ='Maruja'

print(dd('''
         %s:
           _.-.
         '( ^{_}    (
           `~\`-----'\\
              )_)---)_)
         ''' % name))
```

No error but why?

```
$ python3 test2.py    # or python2 test2.py
Maruja:
  _.-.
'( ^{_}    (
  `~\`-----'\
     )_)---)_)
```

I have not been able to figure out why this happens and I have tested in several environments, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your string contains `"{_}"`, which the `format` method will try to replace. Not sure if there's a way to escape it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print a literal "{}" characters in python string and also use .format on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

Comment: @Tim The way to escape it is in the first **Related** question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`format` method considers `{_}` also as one of the named placeholders and it is expecting a key:value pair with the key `_`. As it fails to find a match, it fails with `KeyError: '_'`