# KeyError when using .format on a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string and I want to use **.format** function of python to add some variables in it on runtime, This is my string :

```
'{"auth": {"tenantName": "{Insert String Here}", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "{insert String here}", "password": "{insert String Here}"}}}'
```

when I use .format like this:

```
credentials='{"auth": {"tenantName": "{tenant}", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "{admin}", "password": "{password}"}}}'.format(tenant='me',admin='test',password='123')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: '"auth"'
```

Any Help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you put your full code here ??

Comment: You need to escape the extra `{`s

Comment: This is the complete code so far. I just need to adjust 3 strings where I specified.

Comment: I don't think format can handle the nested braces. You need to the ones that aren't meant for variables.

Comment: Where is the extra '{' @desiredlogin

Comment: I don't get what you said @bnjmn

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`{` and `}` are special characters for string formatting, as you clearly are aware, since you are using them for `{tenant}`, `{admin}` and `{password}`. All the other `{`s and `}`s need to be escaped by doubling them. Try:

```
credentials='{{"auth": {{"tenantName": "{tenant}", "passwordCredentials": {{"username": "{admin}", "password": "{password}"}}}}}}'.format(tenant='me',admin='test',password='123')
```

Comment: Thank god I found your answer after half day headache!

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong tool for your trade. You are dealing with [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads), and you need to use the json library to parse your data and then access your field as a dictionary

```
>>> import json
>>> data_dict = json.loads(data)
>>> data_dict["auth"]["tenantName"]
u'{Insert String Here}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The .format function is choking on your extra { } braces. It's looking for those braces as an indication of what to search and replace, so when it sees those braces it thinks it's looking at a key to replace.

You need to escape the braces that are not meant to indicate keys. For .format, that's done by doubling the brace. So your code should look like:

```
credentials='{{"auth": {{"tenantName": "{tenant}", "passwordCredentials": {{"username": "{admin}", "password": "{password}"}}}}}}'.format(tenant='me',admin='test',password='123')
```

See the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Also see this question:
[How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it doesn't require code, this is clearly a fixed json data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your string begins with `{"auth"`. As soon as the format string parser sees that opening curly brace it thinks that `"auth"` is the name of a format variable as passed in to `.format()`. You need to escape any curly braces in your template string with double curly_braces, like `{{`.

That said, it looks like you're trying to build a JSON string. Just use the json module for that.

Answer (score -1):

I think the braces might be killing you. If you are using format, it expects things inside { } to be keys. That is, I don't think you can use .format in a string which contains non-formatting `{...}' because it doesn't know how to parse it. However, you could do:

```
credentials='["auth": ["tenantName": "{tenant}", "passwordCredentials": ["username": "{admin}", "password": "{password}"]]}'.format(tenant='me',admin='test',password='123')
```

Then do a

```
credentials.replace("[","{")
credentials.replace("]","}")
```

Comment: This is not ideal. See the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Indeed this would just create havoc.