# 'CREATE' in Python String causing KeyError with " 'class' "

Tags: python, cassandra, keyerror, nosql

I'm trying to make a class of commands for Cassandra (A NoSQL database) using "Python-Driver". You can use `session.execute()` to run SQL commands on your Database. Anyway, I'm trying to make a function to create a keyspace.

### Here is the code:

```
def createKeySpace(self, title, class_type='SimpleStrategy', replication_factor='3'):
    self.session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE {} WITH REPLICATION = \
    { 'class' : '{}', 'replication_factor' : {} };\
    ".format(title, class_type, replication_factor))
```

### The issue is, if I try to use this function, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "db_commands.py", line 12, in createKeySpace
    ".format('CREATE', title, class_type, replication_factor))
KeyError: " 'class' "
```

Something I think is worth noting:
I noticed that the `=` sign in my string in Sublime Text is Red while the usual String color is yellow. **If I take out "CREATE" from the string though, the equals sign will return to the color yellow!**

Is this because Python already recognizes CREATE as SQL syntax and doesn't like the way I'm declaring the String with .format()? Any help would be great! :)

Comment: The error doesn't seem to match your code.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7? :P Hopefully it works on 3 as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `format` you need to escape curly braces that are meant to be literal curly braces, e.g.

```
"CREATE {} WITH REPLICATION = \
    {{ 'class' : '{}', 'replication_factor' : {}  }};".format('a','b','c')
```

Comment: Ah... that's pretty obvious. My bad.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your string.format syntax - you get the same error just trying to format that string the way you are doing..

```
title="Title"
class_type="Class_Type"
replication_factor="Rep_Factor"

print("CREATE KEYSPACE {} WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : '{}', 'replication_factor' : {} };".format(title, class_type, replication_factor))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: " 'class' "
```

The issue is that you need to double the `{` and `}` literals for this to work.

```
print("CREATE KEYSPACE {} WITH REPLICATION = \
{{ 'class' : '{}', 'replication_factor' : {} }};\
".format(title, class_type, replication_factor))

CREATE KEYSPACE Title WITH REPLICATION =     { 'class' : 'Class_Type',       'replication_factor' : Rep_Factor };
```

Check [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format) for more details.

Comment: Haha yeah. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
"CREATE KEYSPACE {} WITH REPLICATION={{ 'class' : '{}', 'replication_factor' : {}}};".format(keyspace,'SimpleStrategy',1)
```

You need to escape curly braces that are meant to be literal curly braces, so use one more curly braces to escape them as above.