# python create JSON string throws an exception

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, scrapy

This is the error that I'm getting

```
ERROR:scrapy.core.scraper:Error processing {'action': u'Rent',
 'ad_images': [bla bla bla],
 'ad_link': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'ad_title': u'boa bra bra',
 'agent_fees': 2300.0,
 'amenities': u'boa bra bra',
 'area': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'bathrooms': 1.0,
 'bedrooms': u'1',
 'building': u'',
 'category': u'Apartment',
 'city': -1,
 'commission': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'coordinates': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'country': u'',
 'ded_licence_number': u'718652',
 'description': u'Description:',
 'furnished': u'No',
 'latitude': -1,
 'link': u'bla bla bla',
 'location': u'',
 'longitude': -1,
 'mobile': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'payment_type': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'phone': u'',
 'phoneticarea': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'phoneticbuilding': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'phoneticsubarea': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'posting_date': u'2016-01-04',
 'price': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'price_sqft': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'property_reference': u'Ramzi',
 'rent_is_paid': u'Quarterly',
 'rera_registration_number': u'15691',
 'security_deposit': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'size': 1000.0,
 'source': u'dubizzleproperty',
 'subarea': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'trade_name': u'BLUE HOME PROPERTIES',
 'type': u'does_not_exit_in_this_website',
 'yearly_cost': 43000.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "bra bra bla/pipelines.py", line 70, in process_item
    body = '{"building": "{0}", "area" : "{1}", "subarea" : "{2}", "country" : "{3}", "city" : "{4}", "payment_type" : "{5}", "category" : "{6}", "phoneticbuilding" : "{7}", "phoneticarea" : "{8}", "phoneticssubarea": "{9}" }'.format(building, area, subarea, country, city, payment_type, category, phoneticbuilding, phoneticarea, phoneticssubarea)
KeyError: '"building"'
```

and if you want to know the line 70 of the pipelines file, here you go:

```
body = '{"building": "{0}", "area" : "{1}", "subarea" : "{2}", "country" : "{3}", "city" : "{4}", "payment_type" : "{5}", "category" : "{6}", "phoneticbuilding" : "{7}", "phoneticarea" : "{8}", "phoneticssubarea": "{9}" }'.format(building, area, subarea, country, city, payment_type, category, phoneticbuilding, phoneticarea, phoneticssubarea)
```

Comment: Why are you formatting the JSON yourself instead of using a library for that? Your self-reinvented solution breaks as soon as the inserted elements contain anything interpreted by JSON, too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt a good idea, what do you suggest please ?

Comment: Use a JSON library for Python? Search the web!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm thinking about it. the body variable is just string, even thought its value is in JSON format. so the exception will not be solved using a JSON library. don't you think?

Comment: Just read some documentation and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arthur says you need to replace the single curly brackets with two brackets. I would add that you should do it in the text that will be the key value of the JSON string:

For example (short version of string), replace:

```
body = '{"building": "{0}", "area" : "{1}" }'.format(building, area)
```

with:

```
body = '{{"building": "{0}", "area" : "{1}" }}'.format(building, area)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the non-format `{` and `}` brackets of the body.

Edit : That means replacing them by `{{` and `}}`. See [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

Comment: Those are important to create a JSON file, otherwise, it wouldn't be a JSON formatted string. Don't you think?

Comment: __Escaping__ (not remove, replace by `{{` and `}}`) will avoid `.format` to interpret brackets as replacement directive. They are reserved characters.

Comment: if you know this body = '\{"building": "{0}", "area" : "{1}", "subarea" : "{2}", "country" : "{3}", "city" : "{4}", "payment_type" : "{5}", "category" : "{6}", "phoneticbuilding" : "{7}", "phoneticarea" : "{8}", "phoneticssubarea": "{9}" \}'.format(building, area, subarea, country, city, payment_type, category, phoneticbuilding, phoneticarea, phoneticssubarea)