# Combine same function with different parameters - Python

Tags: python, function

I want to make a tic tac toe game, and I am making it so when the user inputs a number 1 - 9, it makes an X on the corresponding space on the grid. here's the function for that:

```
def move(inp):
    if inp == 1:
        one = " X |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print one
    elif inp == 2:
        two = "   | X |\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print two
    elif inp == 3:
        three = "   |\t| X\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print three
    elif inp == 4:
        four = "   |\t|\n____________\n X |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print four
    elif inp == 5:
        five = "   |\t|\n_____________\n   | X  |\n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print five
    elif inp == 6:
        six = "   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t| X \n_____________\n   |\t|"
        print six
    elif inp == 7:
        seven = "   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n X |\t|"
        print seven
    elif inp == 8:
        eight = "   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n   | X |"
        print eight
    elif inp == 9:
        nine = "   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t|\n_____________\n   |\t| X "
        print nine
```

and so, the grid shows up with the X at the right place. But then the next turn comes. And I want to have them enter a new number, but keep the old X where it was. I was thinking: is there a way to combine that function to itself with a different parameter and have them put two X's on the grid?
So, my question is, is there a function for this, and if not, how would I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this:

```
def make_square(inp):
    square = " {0} |{1}\t|{2}\n_____________\n  {3} | {4}\t|{5}\n_____________\n {6}  |{7}\t|{8}" # set {} brackets for 'X' format
    inp += -1 # rest because need take from 0 as the brackts indice
    for x in range(9): # range max of 'X'
        if x != inp:
            square = square.replace('{{{0}}}'.format(x),' ') # delete brackets without the number select by the user
            # {{ {0} }}  explication http://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/4941927
    square = square.replace('{{{0}}}'.format(inp),'{0}') # convert current {number} into {0} for format
    square = square.format('X') # formatting brackets for the 'X'
    print square

make_square(2)
```

if you need help, I am happy to help
Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

When programming, if you find  yourself copy-pasting the same code over and over, something is wrong.  You should rethink this thing from the start.  How about this?

```
board = [' '] * 9 # the 9 cells, empty at first

def show(board):
    for row in range(3):
        print '|',
        for col in range(3):
            print board[row*3 + col], '|',
        print # newline

def move(inp):
    board[inp-1] = 'X' # user input is 1-based, Python is 0-based
    show(board)
```