# How To Print Character During Parameter Passing

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to make a board that looks like this:

```
x ! x ! x

~ ~ ~ ~ ~

x ! x ! x

~ ~ ~ ~ ~

x ! x ! x
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    print(vert_char*2)
    print(horiz_char*5)
    return

print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')
```

I can't figure out how to get the 'x' to print between the vertical characters. How should I go about this? Is a newline character involved?

Comment: Do you would like to do something like this? [square similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903763/combine-same-function-with-different-parameters-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` to use the `vert_char` to join a list of `x`s. Sth. like so:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    print(vert_char.join(['x']*3))
    print(horiz_char*5)
    print(vert_char.join(['x']*3))
    print(horiz_char*5)
    print(vert_char.join(['x']*3))

print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')

x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
```

or shorter:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    print(('\n'+(horiz_char*5)+'\n').join(vert_char.join(['x']*3) for _ in range(3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char = '', vert_char = ''):
    print(('X '+vert_char)*2+'X')
    if horiz_char != '':
        print(horiz_char*5)
    return

print_tic_tac_toe('~ ', '! ')
print_tic_tac_toe('~ ', '! ')
print_tic_tac_toe('', '! ')
```

Output:

```
X ! X ! X
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
X ! X ! X
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
X ! X ! X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_tic_tac_toe(horiz_char, vert_char):
    print('x %s x %s x' %(vert_char, vert_char))
    print('%s %s %s %s %s' %(horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char))
    print('x %s x %s x' %(vert_char, vert_char))
    print('%s %s %s %s %s' %(horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char, horiz_char))
    print('x %s x %s x' %(vert_char, vert_char))
   

print_tic_tac_toe('~', '!')
```