# escaping one of the keys in formatting a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I was trying to generate a dynamic id which comes from a an object at runtime and insert this into database.

```
'{"mykey": {value}}'.format(value=obj.id)
```

but this gives an error

> KeyError: '"mykey"'

expected result:

```
'{"mykey": 4}' # assuming obj.id = 4
```

I know I can use `json.dumps` but I do not wish to use json for such a simple task and had to resort to:`'{"mykey": %s}' %(obj.id,)`

But I am curious to know a way to do this with **format**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [escape the `{`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format):

```
>>> value = 4
>>> '{{"mykey": {value}}}'.format(value=value)
'{"mykey": 4}'
```

You can also access the object properties inside the format template passing in `obj` in a context:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Object = namedtuple('Object', 'id')
>>> obj = Object(id=4)
>>> obj.id
4
>>> '{{"mykey": {obj.id}}}'.format(obj=obj)
'{"mykey": 4}'
```

---

Same goes for the [format strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) coming up in [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html):

```
>>> value = 4
>>> f'{{"mykey": {value}}}'
'{"mykey": 4}'
```