# How to use str.format inside a string of json format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string-formatting

Python Version 3.5

I'm trying to make an API call to configure a device using json as the format. Some of the json will vary depending on the desired naming, so I need to call a variable in the string. I am able to accomplish this using the old style `%s... % (variable)`, but not with the new style `{}... .format(variable)`.

Failed EX:

```
(Testing with {"fvAp":{"attributes":{"name":(variable)}}})

a = "\"app-name\""

app_config = ''' { "fvAp": { "attributes": { "name": {} }, "children": [ { "fvAEPg": { "attributes": { "name": "app" }, "children": [ { "fvRsBd": { "attributes": { "tnFvBDName": "default" }, } } ] } }, { "fvAEPg": { "attributes": { "name": "db" }, "children": [ { "fvRsBd": { "attributes": { "tnFvBDName": "default" }, } } ] } } ] } } '''.format(a)

print(app_config)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/..., line 49, in '''.format('a') KeyError: '\n "fvAp"'

Working EX:

```
a = "\"app-name\""

app_config = ''' { "fvAp": { "attributes": { "name": %s }, "children": [ { "fvAEPg": { "attributes": { "name": "app" }, "children": [ { "fvRsBd": { "attributes": { "tnFvBDName": "default" }, } } ] } }, { "fvAEPg": { "attributes": { "name": "db" }, "children": [ { "fvRsBd": { "attributes": { "tnFvBDName": "default" }, } } ] } } ] } } ''' % a

print(app_config)
```

How do I get this to work using `str.format` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print a literal "{}" characters in python string and also use .format on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-a-literal-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-format)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section says:

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

So if you want to use `.format` method, you need to escape all JSON curly braces in your template string:

```
>>> '{{"fvAp": {{"attributes": {{"name": {}}}}}}}'.format('"app-name"')
'{"fvAp": {"attributes": {"name": "app-name"}}}'
```

That looks really bad.

There's a better way to do that with [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> t = Template('{"fvAp": {"attributes": {"name": "${name}"}}')
>>> t.substitute(name='StackOverflow')
'{"fvAp": {"attributes": {"name": "StackOverflow"}}'
```

Though I suggest abandoning the idea of generating configs this way altogether and using a factory function and [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) instead:

```
>>> import json
>>> def make_config(name):
...     return {'fvAp': {'attributes': {'name': name}}}
>>> app_config = make_config('StackOverflow')
>>> json.dumps(app_config)
'{"fvAp": {"attributes": {"name": "StackOverflow"}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to substitute dynamic values within a json file with their runtime counterparts.
You can use `PLACEHOLDER` in this scenario.
Construct your json using `PLACEHOLDER` values where you would like to substitute them with dynamic values.

For example:

```
{
    "services": [{
            "name": "service_a",
            "config": {
                "dynamic_value_1": "PLACEHOLDER",
                "dynamic_value_2": "PLACEHOLDER"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "service_b",
            "config": {
                "dynamic_value_1": "PLACEHOLDER",
                "dynamic_value_2": "PLACEHOLDER"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then read the json file and perform an update by passing a dictionary of values you want to substitute.

```
def dynamic_values() -> Dict:
        """
        Provides a map of placeholder values with their dynamic counterparts
        """
        return {
            "service_a": {
                "dynamic_value_1": service_a_method_1(),
                "dynamic_value_2": service_a_method_2(),
            },
            "service_b": {
                "dynamic_value_1": service_b_method_1(),
                "dynamic_value_2": service_b_method_1(),
            },
        }


def load_dynamic_values(dynamic_values) -> List:
        """
        Overrides placeholder values in json file with dynamic values at runtime
        """
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        services = data["services"]
        for s in services:
            override = dynamic_values.get(s["name"], None)
            if override:
                s["config"].update(override)
        return services
```