# Using string formatting on JSON objects parsed as strings

Tags: python, json, formatting

How do you use string formatting on a json string or other strings that have brackets?
This, you would work with as a dictionary, but I can't think of a good example:

```
payload = '''
{"accessToken": "{accessToken}","clientToken": "{clientToken}"}
'''.format(clientToken = clientToken, accessToken = accessToken)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use python str.format inside a string of json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948645/how-to-use-python-str-format-inside-a-string-of-json-format)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much.