# Can't escape and parse characters in Python string formatting

Tags: python, string, pandas, curly-braces, html-escape-characters

Found this link already:

[How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

Didn't quite get me to where I need to go as I have some crazy characters in this string. I need to be able to keep the outer curly brackets (in the line starting with ':9502...'), while being able to format the {0}.

```
    try:
    filtered_df['Path'] = \
        filtered_df['Path'].apply(lambda x: '<a href="http://'
                                            + host
                                            + ':9502/analytic/saw.dll?catalog#{"location"%3A"{0}"}" target="_blank">{1}</a>'.format(urllib.quote(x, safe=''), x))
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to simply change some of my column values in a pandas dataframe to an html link. The issue is the required formatting of the destination link (the portion detailed below):

```
catalog#{"location"%3A"{0}"}" target="_blank">{1}</a>'.format(urllib.quote(x, safe=''), x))
```

Suffice to say it's pretty crazy and that's how it has to look to get to where I need to go. The issue is is that it doesn't allow the app to execute as written, so the problem, at least I'm guessing, is that I need to do something about those curly brackets and maybe some of the quotes?

Answer (score 3):

You escape the curly braces by doubling them up.

```
'outside{{inside {0}}}'.format('stuff')

'outsid{inside stuff}'
```