# Python - string as key to named-variable format string

Tags: python, string, google-api, string-formatting, pagespeed

I'm using Google's PageSpeed Insights API in Python, and I've come across a baffling issue. The API presents me with a format string and arguments to that format string, and I need to figure out how to actually format the string. The problem is that the arguments are given in a really odd fashion.

This is how the arguments to the format string are presented to me (I'm showing it as an assignment to make it clearer):

```
args = [
    {
        'type':  'INT_LITERAL', 
        'value': '21', 
        'key':   'NUM_SCRIPTS'
    }, 
    {
        'type':  'INT_LITERAL', 
        'value': '20', 
        'key':   'NUM_CSS'
    }
]
```

And this is a sample format string, also given to me by the API:

```
format = 'Your page has {{NUM_SCRIPTS}} blocking script resources and {{NUM_CSS}} blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.'
```

I know that sometimes people like to avoid answering the question asked and instead offer an answer that is tailored to their beliefs about coding 'right' and 'wrong,' so to reiterate, I am given both the arguments and the format string by the API. I am not creating them myself, so I can't do this in a more straightforward fashion.

What I need to know is how to extract the key field of the dicts in the args list so that I can use them with `"".format` in a way that will let me pass the value field to the named arguments.

I apologize if this is somehow super obvious; I'm fairly new to Python and I don't know a lot about the little details. I did do my due diligence and search for an answer before asking, but I didn't find anything and it's not an easily searchable problem.

**EDIT:**
I thought maybe this 'list of dicts' thing was commonplace with Google's APIs or something, that maybe there was an automatic way to associate the arguments (like `string.format_map`). I ended up just doing it the simple way, without `string.format`.

```
for x in args:
    format = format.replace('{{' + x['key'] + '}}', x['value'])
```

Comment: Is this what you want? for NUM_CSS `(item for item in args if item["key"] == "NUM_CSS").next()['value']` and for NUM_SCRIPTS `(item for item in args if item["key"] == "NUM_SCRIPTS").next()['value']`

Comment: That list is, frankly, nonsense. Your goal is to look up values for `NUM_SCRIPTS` and `NUM_CSS`, but that list only allows you to search it for values for a certain key for which there's a different key with another value. It should be `args = {'NUM_SCRIPTS':21, 'NUM_CSS':20}` to be even remotely useful without a whole bunch of bad code.

Comment: @Rohanil - No, different format strings have different types and numbers of variables, I can't hard code the names.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know it's nonsense. That's what the API gives me, so that's what I have to work with. If I could do it differently, I would. It looks like I could have to write out long, dirty if-elif-else chains to handle different PageSpeed rules manually, which is hardly future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

If your format string is like so:

```
fmt = 'blah {NUM_SCRIPTS} foo {NUM_CSS} bar'
```

And you have a dictionary of keys and values called **args**, then you can format the string using the dictionary as so:

```
fmt.format(**arg)
```

This would print:

```
"blah 21 foo 20 bar"
```

Comment: Except the values are stored in separate dicts inside a list, not necessarily ordered, so I need to somehow use the key field of each dict to associate it with the named argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `format` string only had one set of brackets, you could do:

```
format_dict = {}
for d in args:
    format_dict[d['key']] = d['value']

str_to_format = 'Your page has {NUM_SCRIPTS} blocking script resources and {NUM_CSS} blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.'

formatted = str_to_format.format(**format_dict)

print(formatted)
# Your page has 21 blocking script resources and 20 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
```

but as `format` is currently written (with two brackets per substitution variable), I'm not sure how to get `format()` to play nice. If you want brackets to surround each substitution variable *after* the substitution variable has been made, you need an [extra set of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo):

```
format_dict = {}
for d in args:
    format_dict[d['key']] = d['value']

str_to_format = 'Your page has {{{NUM_SCRIPTS}}} blocking script resources and {{{NUM_CSS}}} blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.'

formatted = str_to_format.format(**format_dict)

print(formatted)
# Your page has {21} blocking script resources and {20} blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
```

So, depending on your requirements, either add or remove a set of brackets. To add brackets, you could do something like this

```
import re
str_to_format = re.sub('{{|}}', lambda x: x.group(0) + x.group(0)[0], str_to_format)
```