# How to escape curly-brackets in f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curly-braces, f-string

I have a string in which I would like curly-brackets, but also take advantage of the f-strings feature. Is there some syntax that works for this?

Here are two ways it does not work. I would like to include the literal text `{bar}` as part of the string.

```
foo = "test"
fstring = f"{foo} {bar}"
```

`NameError: name 'bar' is not defined`

```
fstring = f"{foo} \{bar\}"
```

`SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`

Desired result:

```
'test {bar}'
```

Edit: Looks like this question has the same answer as [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in a string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo), but you can only know that if you know that `str.format` uses the same rules as the f-string. So hopefully this question has value in tying f-string searchers to this answer.

Comment: you can replace '{' and '}'  to their corresponding codepoint `\u007b` and `\u007d`.For example `print(' \u007b \u007d')` got  `{ }`

Comment: This should actually be an/the answer because the doubling the braces does not work if you want to print a single brace. Oh my do I feel dirty now.

Comment: @stefanct What do you mean does not work? `f'{{1{2}'` correctly returns `'{12'`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but there are lots of cases where it does not work, e.g., `f'{{}'` -> `SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed`

Comment: @stefanct still not seeing the problem - what do you think that should return? why using an f prefix at all if you’re not formatting any fields?

Comment: you are missing the point. it does not work with fields either. i don't know why it works with your examples - probably some funny parser quirk with numeric literals but single parentheses are not universally supported in f-strings.

Comment: Yes I am missing the point because you haven't showed an example of what you mean. Formatting a single brace 'not working' is clearly incorrect, `f"{{{name}"` gives a formatted string with a single leading brace, and has nothing to do with numeric literals.

Answer (score 483, accepted):

Although there is a custom syntax error from the parser, the [same trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466451/674039) works as for calling `.format` on regular strings.

Use double curlies:

```
>>> foo = 'test'
>>> f'{foo} {{bar}}'
'test {bar}'
```

It's mentioned in the spec [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification) and the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals).

Comment: If you need double curlies in the output, use quadruple curlies: `f'{foo} {{{{bar}}}}'`.

Comment: What if one wants to wrap the value of the variable in `{ }`?

Comment: Would something like this work in a JINJA template?

Comment: @GeorgeIrwin triple braces will do the trick for that