# Is there anyway to get { as a normal caracter with f' before ? python

Tags: python

I don't think the title of my question is very helpful but let me explain my self here :

I have a code , wich is like that

```
Age = 18
print(f'{Age} = {Age}')
```

Expected Output :

```
{Age} = 18
```

Is there anyway to get { as a normal caracter with f' before ?
*I would like to have one as F string , other as text .*

Comment: Potential duplicate: [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo). It's more of a dupe of [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521230/how-to-escape-f-strings-in-python-3-6), but that's been marked a dupe of the first link.

Comment: Remember to post your research, and if none remember to do some before posting. Most questions already has an answer out there.

Comment: `f'{{Age}} = {Age}'`