# Python F string, insert string with curly brackets inside curly bracket

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I have a list of values I want to insert inside the parenthesis in an *f-string*.
The length of the list will be different from time to time, therefore, I will make a string with the correct length for each case. The idea was to create a *string* of proper length and then insert it into the *f-string*. This fails because it is read as a *string*.

Is it other workarounds to get the same result or is it a feature with the *f-strings* I do not know about? This is my code so far:

```
values = [['First Name Last name', 20],['First Name Last name', 25],['First Name Last name', 30]]
test = [1]*3
for i in range(3):
    val = f'''values[{i}]''' #First create innerpart
    test[i] = f'''({{{val}}})''' #Then encapsulate it in curly brackets and paranthesis
insert = ' '.join(test)
f'''Test {insert}'''
```

The output:

```
'Test ({values[0]}) ({values[1]}) ({values[2]})'
```

My desired output:

```
'Test('First Name Last Name',20) ('First Name Last Name',25) ('First Name Last Name',30)'
```

I have tried to find ways of escaping the quoting in a string without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape curly-brackets in f-strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521230/how-to-escape-curly-brackets-in-f-strings). In summary, you have to use 2 brackets instead of one.

Comment: `test[i] = f"({values[i]})"` you can use list indexing (or pretty much any python expression) in an f string. The contents of the string have nothing to do with how you insert it into an fstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simpler approach is what you need:

```
string = "Test"
for val in values:
    string += f"({', '.join(str(elem) for elem in val)}) "
print(string[:-1])
```

Output:

```
'Test(First Name Last name, 20) (First Name Last name, 25) (First Name Last name, 30)'
```

There is no need to escape curly brackets, just concatenate all the elements within each list and format them properly.