# How to use awk in Python subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, linux, awk

Below is my Python code, I need to use awk to grep one of the process(SWeNP) number running inside k8s pod.

```
cs_swo_cmd = f"oc exec -it {pod_name} bash -c cs-container -- ps -eaf | grep -i 'SWe_NP' | awk \'{print $2}\'"
swo_process = subprocess.Popen(cs_swo_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But when I am running the code, getting below error, please HELP.

```
stella@bts16:~$ python3 k8sSwitchover.py
  File "k8sSwitchover.py", line 70
    cs_swo_cmd = f"oc exec -it $i bash -c cs-container -- ps -eaf | grep -i 'SWe_NP' | awk {'print $2}"
                 ^
SyntaxError: f-string: unterminated string
stella@bts16:~$
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521252/2221001  Use double curly brackets in your awk script to escape them from the f-string. Also drop those `\\` as there doesn't appear to be any reason to escape single quotes in that f-string.

Comment: To improve readability, i would just do `"oc exec -it "+pod_name+" bash -c cs-container -- ps -eaf | grep -i 'SWe_NP' | awk '{print $2}'"`, without f-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead for `cw_swo_cmd`:

```
cs_swo_cmd = f"oc exec -it {pod_name} bash -c cs-container -- ps -eaf | grep -i 'SWe_NP' | awk '{{print $2}}'"
```

Should give the correct result:

```
"oc exec -it $i bash -c cs-container -- ps -eaf | grep -i 'SWe_NP' | awk '{print $2}'"
```