# python command formatting of Ubuntu command in a list

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

This is the formatting done for this ubuntu command **egrep -v "usernameshere"**
in python as bellow

```
userfilter = ["egrep", "-v", "\"{filter}\"".format(filter=filteruser)]
```

**Why doing:**
I am passing this to a subprocess and executing the command from python.

Now I want to accomplish the same for this command how to do it.

```
awk '{gsub("admin","");print}'
```

I tried the below one but not working, some syntax errors

**Try 1**

```
userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub({filter},\"\");print}\'".format(filter=filteruser)]
```

**Try 2**

```
userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub({filter}.format(filter=filteruser),\"\");print}\'"]
```

**Errors:**

TRY 1 Error:

```
userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub({filter},\"\");print}\'".format(f‌​ilter=filteruser)] KeyError: 'gsub({filter},"");print'
```

TRY 2 Error:

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
awk: line 1: extra ')'
```

Comment: What is the specific syntax error that you've encountered?

Comment: `userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub({filter},\"\");print}\'".format(filter=filteruser)]
KeyError: 'gsub({filter},"");print'` in first Case

Comment: I suppose your having issues with the usage of multiple curly brackets. Try this instead `userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub("+filteruser+",\"\");print}\'"]`

Comment: Here's a great answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo

Answer (score 0):

So basically the usage of multiple curly brackets is giving you syntax issue. Simply use double curly brackets to print actual curly brackets in your string.

```
userfilter=["awk","\'{{gsub({filter},\"\");print}}\'".format(filter=filteruser)]
```

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   {}. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include
>   a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
>   {{ and }}.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

I'm not sure how your encountering the second error, because when I copy paste this to my terminal, I get no error, but simply a string literal.

```
>>> userfilter=["awk","\'{gsub({filter}.format(filter=filteruser),\"\");print}\'"]
>>> userfilter
['awk', '\'{gsub({filter}.format(filter=filteruser),"");print}\'']
```

Comment: The error comes when i use that in subprocess and run it ,Its obviously not going to run if we simply check the variable

Comment: As the document states, simply use double curly brackets if you want include a brace character in the literal text. . `userfilter=["awk","\'{{gsub({filter}.format(filter=filteruser),\"\");print}}\'"]`

Comment: that didn't work `awk: 1: unexpected character '''
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near |`