# How may I dynamically insert a string into a large javascript template string in python?

Tags: javascript, python, string

Suppose a template javascript string like this:

```
js_string = u'function hello() { alert({0}); } function goodbye() { alert({1}); }'
```

I would like to get following result:

```
function hello() { alert('Hello!'); } function goodbye() { alert('Goodbye!'); }
```

My initial idea was to use the .format() method, which resulted in a KeyError due to the arbitrary curly braces. I then had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo) question and replaced said curly braces with double curly braces. Although this produces the desired result, I cannot use it, as I'm working with a rather large javascript template and am not up for changing each and every single curly brace.

I have also tried the .replace() function:

```
js_string.replace("{0}", repr("Hello!")).replace("{1}", repr("Goodbye!"))
```

However, calling .replace() more than once seems inconvenient to me, which is why I am asking if there is any straightforward alternative for this problem.

Comment: Are you inserting anything other than data into the template? You could just make a template with only variable definitions and add the actual code separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're set on curly brace syntax, you can simply call `.replace` in a loop. No need for regexes.

```
for i, replacement in enumerate(["'hello'", "'Goodbye!'"]):
    js_string = js_string.replace('{%s}' % i, replacement)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the replacement with one call to `sub` by supplying a callback function that reads the number inside braces, and grabs the corresponding replacement word from a list:

```
re.sub(r'\{(\d+)\}', lambda m: ["'hello'", "'Goodbye!'"][int(m.group(1))], js_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation with the `%` operator:

```
>>> u'function hello() { alert(%r); } function goodbye() { alert(%r); }' % ('Hello', 'Goodbye')
"function hello() { alert('Hello'); } function goodbye() { alert('Goodbye'); }"
```

Here `%r` means use the `repr`, if you want to insert the string directly use `%s`. `%%` is a literal `%`.

More details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations