# Escape single '{' in python

Tags: python, curly-braces

I am using python for C code generation, I want to have a function that prints the following:

```
{
.data1="egg",
.data2="dog",
},
```

I tried this function:

```
def funky(data1,data2):
    return """\
    {
    .data1="egg",
    .data2="dog",
    },""".format(data1,data2)
```

Calling "`funky("egg","dog")`" results in a KeyError. Relating to the unpaired curly braces.

How can I print these braces?

Comment: Why are you using `format` at all when your format string is completely hardcoded, with no format placeholders?

Comment: escape single `{` with double `{{`.

Comment: Seems to me, like this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo).

Comment: Thank you @Daniel , that solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to:

1. Use two `{`s and two `}`s.
2. Escape the double quotes inside the string.
3. Use `{0}` and `{1}` instead of `{egg}` and `{dog}`.

---

```
def funky(data1,data2):
    return """\
    {{
    .data1=\"{0}\",
    .data2=\"{1}\",
    }},""".format(data1,data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no variables in your string literal, you didn't escape the `{` and `}`, and you broke the indentation. Try this:

```
def stripMargin(txt):
  return '\n'.join([r.split('|', 1)[1] for r in txt.split('\n')])

def funky(data1,data2):
  return stripMargin("""|{{
  |.data1="{0}",
  |.data2="{1}",
  |}},""".format(data1,data2))

print(funky("egg", "dog"))
```

The `|`-part combined with `stripMargin` ensures that the indentation of the generated code (the object language) does not interfere with the indentation of python (the metalanguage).

I would actually indent the generated code differently:

```
def funky(data1,data2):
  return stripMargin("""|{{
  |  .data1="{0}",
  |  .data2="{1}",
  |}},""".format(data1,data2))
```

---

Since you don't need any common indentation in the final output, you can also use `dedent`:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def funky2(data1,data2):
    return dedent("""\
    {{
    .data1="{0}",
    .data2="{1}",
    }},""").format(data1,data2)
```

(Thanks @user2357112 for pointing it out)

Comment: The closest thing to Scala's `stripMargin` in Python is [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent).

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the hint! Added a variation with `dedent`.