# Setting up verbose regex

Tags: python, regex

While trying to set up a verbose regex:

```
# set up variables
ankerwords = ['beerdigt','bestattet','begraben','beigesetzt']

# combine the words, five words before/after
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:\b\w+\W+){5} # five words before
    (?:{})
    (?:\W+\w+\b){5} # five words thereafter
    '''.format("|".join(ankerwords)), re.X)
```

This throws an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

---

I know it's because of the `{5}` in the expression but how to get around it **without splitting the string in several parts**, i.e.

```
'''(?:\b\w+\W+){5}''' + '(?:{})'.format(...)
```

It's more a question of style, really.

Comment: something like: `(?:\b\w+\W+){{5}}` or use legacy `%` formatting

Comment: @Jan the extra `{..}` escape the `{..}` that format uses for replacement, and leave the extra `{..}` of the regex intact

Comment: If your concern is stylistic, you could also use f-strings with the double brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doubling the braces work, it tells `format` to consider the curly braces as a normal char (it escapes them: [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)):

```
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:\b\w+\W+){{5}} # five words before
    (?:{})
    (?:\W+\w+\b){{5}} # five words thereafter
    '''.format("|".join(ankerwords)), re.X)
```

or using old style `%` formatting:

```
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:\b\w+\W+){5} # five words before
    (?:%s)
    (?:\W+\w+\b){5} # five words thereafter
    ''' % ("|".join(ankerwords)), re.X)
```

another way in that case, since the `{5}` is repeated, maybe like this:

```
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:\b\w+\W+){five} # five words before
    (?:{expr})
    (?:\W+\w+\b){five} # five words thereafter
    '''.format(expr="|".join(ankerwords),five="{5}", re.X)
```

(which avoids to double the braces and allows to "parametrize" the number of words once and for all)

Answer (score 3):

Jean covered pretty much every way of escaping curly braces quite well. The only thing I'd add is if your concern is stylistic, and you have the luxury of using `Python 3.6+`, then you can make it slightly more readable with

```
rx = re.compile(fr'''
    (?:\b\w+\W+){{5}} # five words before
    (?:{"|".join(ankerwords)})
    (?:\W+\w+\b){{5}} # five words thereafter
    ''', re.X)
```