# KeyError building parametrized string containing ':'

Tags: python

Let's say, I need to build a series of strings based on this pattern:

```
pattern="{app: }"
```

with an ultimate goal of generating the below sequence:

> "{app: MS Office }"
>
> "{app: Notepad }"
>   etc.

I'm trying to do that using the format method, like so

```
insert="MS Office"
result=pattern.format(insert)
```

However, all I get back is

> KeyError: 'app'

It does look like the error is caused by Python misinterpreting the colon in the pattern, but what how do I get around it? I do need the colon.

Thanks.

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape braces:

```
In [1]: pattern = '{{app: {}}}'

In [2]: pattern.format('MS Office')
Out[2]: '{app: MS Office}'
```

Comment: Sure, it works. Could you _explain_ the double curly braces on the outside, please?

Comment: You need to escape `{` and `}` if you want to keep them in resulting string. `format` interprets `{app}` as a place to insert value passed as `app='something'` to the function

Comment: And I'm escaping them with another set of curly braces?

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pattern="{{app: {0} }}"

insert="MS Office"
result=pattern.format(insert)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{app: MS Office }
```