# How do I cleanly format a string in Python with multiple {} that also need to be ignored?

Tags: python, format, splunk

Setting up search queries in Python for Splunk access. However, during my runs I ran into a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I found in my code multiple {} and trying to use .format to apply variables earliest and latest was causing said error.

I've tried switching to .format_map but it causes more error unless I did something wrong. (Which could be)

I am not able to change the string that is in the code. So I am trying to find ways to append time variables to the string for use.

Here are the variable calls:

```
import _datetime_param
_earliest = _datetime_param.earliest()
_latest = _datetime_param.latest()
```

Formatting Works:

```
def eop():
    search_query = (
        'index="eop" sourcetype="eop:trace" Status="Quarantined" earliest={} latest={} | '
        'convert timeformat="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S" ctime(_time) as Date | '
        'table Date src_ip src_user subject recipient | sort Date'
    ).format(_earliest, _latest)
    search_query.strip()
    if not (search_query.startswith('search') or search_query.startswith('|')):
        search_query = 'search ' + search_query
    return search_query
```

Formatting Runs Into Error:

```
def okta():
    search_query = (
        'index="okta" user!="CityADSync" action="failure" earliest={} latest={} | '
        'convert timeformat="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S" ctime(_time) AS Date | dedup actors{}.ipAddress | '
        'rename actors{}.ipAddress AS IPAddress | rename actors{}.id AS Device | rename targets{}.id AS TargetID | '
        'rename targets{}.displayName AS TargetName| rename targets{}.login AS TargetLogin | '
        'table Date Device IPAddress TargetID TargetName TargetLogin | sort Date'
    ).format(_earliest, _latest)
    search_query.strip()
    if not (search_query.startswith('search') or search_query.startswith('|')):
        search_query = 'search ' + search_query
    return search_query
```

In the `def okata():` I can't change the `search_query` as its set to run that way in Splunk. So I am looking for a way to cleanly handle both ways while not running into error. Put bluntly is there a way in Python to ignore {} you don't want to use? If it is `.format_map`, is there a clean way to do so that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

Comment: I saw that post and while helpful, it does not work in this situation. The strings cannot change nor am I trying to print with brackets. I am trying to append time variables to the string but only in the spots needed whilst ignoring others. Hopefully this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I can use [f String](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) .

Your string stay as:

`string = f' a text {var} other text {other_var}'`

Comment: Tried this, just comes back with an error of: ```SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed```

Comment: Build query with string don't help you with code clean, but see if this solve your problem

```search_query = f"index=okta user!=CityADSync action=failure earliest={_earliest} latest={_latest} | convert timeformat=%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S ctime(_time) AS Date | dedup actors{{{''}}}.ipAddress | rename actors{{{''}}}.ipAddress AS IPAddress | rename actors{{{''}}}.id AS Device | rename targets{{{''}}}.id AS TargetID | rename targets{{{''}}}.displayName AS TargetName| rename targets{{{''}}}.login AS TargetLogin | table Date Device IPAddress TargetID TargetName TargetLogin | sort Date"```

Comment: Ahh I see what you did differently. I didn't bracket out the others. Though I was able to get away with just doing `dedup actors{{}}.ipAddress` for example. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah! Using ```{{}}``` you have the same result.