# python format function with { }

Tags: python, format

Is there a way I can get this output using the format function

```
name1 = 'test1'
name2 = 'test2'
ps_script = """powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 {} {} abc}""".format(name1,name2)
print(ps_script)
```

Output Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 6, in
>   
>       ps_script = """powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 {} {} abc}""".format(name1,name2) KeyError:
>   'D'

Expecting output 
powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 test1 test2 abc}

Comment: `ps_script = """powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {{D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 {} {} abc}}""".format(name1,name2)
`?

Comment: Don't use string formatting to create a command line. Use a tool that lets you pass a *list* of arguments rather than a single line to be processed by a shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape to get the literal chars:

```
name1 = 'test1'
name2 = 'test2'
ps_script = """powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {{D:\\abc\\abc\\abc\\abc.ps1 {} {} abc}}""".format(name1,name2)
print(ps_script)
```

OUTPUT:

```
powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 test1 test2 abc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double `{{` to get the literal `{`

```
ps_script = """powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {{D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 {} {} abc}}""".format(name1,name2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a string to run a command like this, you may want to consider using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with a list of arguments (as chepner suggested in the comments) instead.

Maybe like this (notice I added an r to make it a raw string; you want to do this when you are entering backslashes so they aren't interpreted as escape characters):

```
from subprocess import run

cmds_start = r'powershell.exe Start-Job -ScriptBlock {D:\abc\abc\abc\abc.ps1 abc}'.split()
names = 'test1 test2'.split()

cmds = cmds_start[:-1] + names + cmds_start[-1:]

run(cmds)  # use commands list to run, not string

# but can still view the script like:
print(" ".join(cmds))  # or:
print(*cmds, sep=" ")
```