# Remove over powershell windows 10 Apps

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10

I build a script to remove Windows 10 Apps per Python.
I saved the apps to remove in a String Array and save the complete command in a variable.

Then I run the command, come a Error with: **The Remove-AppxPackage command is either misspelled or
could not be found.**

And I have coded following code:

```
    win10Apps = ["3d", "camera"]
       for app in win10Apps:
       psCommand = "Get-AppxPackage " + app + " | Remove-AppxPackage"
       pyautogui.press("Enter")
       os.system("powershell.exe " + psCommand)
       pyautogui.press("Enter")
```

Comment: Read the error message? x marks the spot.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to fix indentation in your [mcve].  Try `os.system('powershell.exe -c "{}"'.format( psCommand))`.

Comment: Okay thank you!
The code works now! @JosefZ

Answer (score 0):

As JosefZ mentioned in the comments, you have to format your parameter when calling other executable.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
win10Apps = ["3d", "camera"]
for app in win10Apps:
    psCommand = "Get-AppxPackage " + app + " | Remove-AppxPackage"
    pyautogui.press("Enter")
    os.system('powershell.exe -c "{}"'.format( psCommand))
    pyautogui.press("Enter")
```

Also for special characters you [need to escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812801/python-format-function-with). Also, here is the documentation for [Get-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps) and for [Remove-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps).