# Create n dictionaries of unique names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
standards = ['1', '2', '3']
sections = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]

classes_maker_counter = 0
for i in standards:
    for j in sections[classes_maker_counter]:
        for k in j:
            classes = f"alloted_{i}_{k}= {}"
            todisplay = f"to_display_{i}_{k} = {}"
            exec(classes)
            exec(todisplay)
    classes_maker_counter += 1
```

when i run this i get this error

```
    f-string: empty expression not allowed
```

is there a way to do this...

Comment: Could you be more specific about the desired output?

Comment: Yes, there is - although I question your reasons for wanting to do this!

Comment: This is a bad idea. Use a dict instead, see the duplicate for more details and solutions.

Comment: I voted for the dupe (`...variable number of variables`) - that's the way you should do it - constructed strings as keys in a dictionary but... Related: [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say that this seems like a terrible idea, but to make your code work you need to create a separate string for your "empty dictionary" that isn't an `f-string`. Like this:

```
classes = f"alloted_{i}_{k} = " + "{}"
todisplay = f"to_display_{i}_{k} = " + "{}"
```

Quite how you plan on using/accessing these variables later is another question entirely... but this is what you asked for!