# How to insert variable into escaped string literal?

Tags: python, string, format

I'm calling an API that will require dynamic variables as parameters. However, I do not know how to format the string to include variables when it is surrounded by triple quotes and a backslash escape character at the beginning of the string literal.

I've tried varying the amount of quotes and using the ".format()" function.

Here is code formatted in a way that gets a successful result:

```
payload = "{\n\t\"firm\": \"myfirm\",\n\t\"id\": \"f87987562\",\n\t\"data\": {\n\t\t\"tracking_preference\": 2\n\t} \n}\n"
```

Here is my attempt at trying to format the string in a cleaner way while also including variables:

```
payload = \
    """{
    "firm": {0},
    "id": {1},
    "data": {
        "tracking_preference": {2}
    } 
}
""".format('myfirm', "f87987562", 2)
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
     19     } 
     20 }
---> 21 """.format('myfirm', "f87987562", 2)
     22 
     23 apikey = "secret_key"

KeyError: '\n    "firm"'
```

I suspect it has something to do with the backslash, but its implementation seems necessary. Any help and insight on the intuition behind this string formatting is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to pass the string literal into the request function:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo). Try `payload = \
    """{{
    "firm": {0},
    "id": {1},
    "data": {{
        "tracking_preference": {2}
    }} 
}}
""".format('myfirm', "f87987562", 2)`

Comment: The problem isn't the backslash, the problem is that `format` is looking at everything inside of curly brackets, which is everything in your string. Why not use a normal `dict` and convert it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a format string, `{` and `}` are special.  To embed a literal parenthesis, use `{{` or `}}`.

```
payload = """{{
    "firm": "{0}",
    "id": "{1}",
    "data": {{
        "tracking_preference": {2}
    }}
}}
""".format('myfirm', "f87987562", 2)

print(payload)
```

Output:

```
{
    "firm": "myfirm",
    "id": "f87987562",
    "data": {
        "tracking_preference": 2
    }
}
```

In Python 3.6+, f-strings can make this simpler:

```
firm = 'myfirm'
id = 'f87987562'
tracking = 2

payload = f'''{{
    "firm": "{firm}",
    "id": "{id}",
    "data": {{
        "tracking_preference": {tracking}
    }}
}}'''
```

Finally, the `json` module is ideal for this specific scenario:

```
import json

firm = 'myfirm'
id = 'f87987562'
tracking = 2

data = {'firm':firm,'id':id,'data':{'tracking_preference':tracking}}
payload = json.dumps(data,indent=2) # indent is optional for easy reading
print(payload)
```

Output:

```
{
  "firm": "myfirm",
  "id": "f87987562",
  "data": {
    "tracking_preference": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3.6+, you could use an f-string:

```
payload = \
    f"""{
    "firm": {"myfirm"},
    "id": {"f87987562"},
    "data": {
        "tracking_preference": {2}
    } 
}
"""
```

If not, you might be better off with a string template:

```
from string import Template

payload_t = Template(
    """{
    "firm": ${firm},
    "id": ${id},
    "data": {
        "tracking_preference": ${tracking}
    } 
}
""")

payload = payload_t.substitute(firm="myfirm", id="f87987562", tracking=2)
```