# String Formatting a stringified dictionary using .format()

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
value  = '{"a" : 0, "b": 6, "c" : {REPLACE}}'
replace = {'REPLACE' : "Replace String"}

value.format(**replace)
value.format(replace)
```

is giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"a"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `{` braces are part of the formatting language to escape them you need to double them `{{`, so:

```
In []:
value  = '{{"a" : 0, "b": 6, "c" : {REPLACE}}}'
replace = {'REPLACE' : "Replace String"}

value.format(**replace)

Out[]:
'{"a" : 0, "b": 6, "c" : Replace String}'
```

Comment: in this case, it works if I escape it, How do i go about it if I am trying to replace a bunch of strings in HTML/JS files?

Comment: Why not just use `str.replace()` - `value.replace('REPLACE', "'Replace String'")`?

Comment: My use case is more restrictive -  I am trying to generalise a function which will replace different set of 'strings' in different files using key: values generated dynamically.

Comment: You may want to ask a specific question on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `{}` with another `{}`. Here is an example:

```
'{{"a" : 0, "b": 6, "c" : "{}"}}'.format("Replace String")
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo) for detailed explanation.