# Python string formatting when already "{}" in the string

Tags: python, string, formatting

I would like to know how could I format this string:

```
"){e<=2}"
```

This string is inside a function, so I would like to asign the number to a function parameter to change it whenever I want.

I tried:

```
"){e<={0}}".format(number)
```

But it is not working, 
Could anybody give me some advice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `{{` and `}}` would not be considered as placeholders by `format`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo, so you can write `"){{e<={0}}}"` instead of `"{e<={0}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the braces which do not correspond to the format placeholder...

```
"){{e<={0}}}".format(number)
```

You could also use an f-string, if using Python 3.6 or above.

```
f"){{e<={number}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

An old-school version for this:

```
"){e<=%d}" % (number)
'){e<=2}'
```