# Why doesn't the operator% in a string show error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I was writing a little code, that I left below:

```
"""
    for(i=0;i<{0};i++){
    eventObj
    }
    """.format('5')
```

it shows the next error:

```
KeyError: '\n    eventObj\n    '
```

but if I write:

```
"""
    for(i=0;i<%s;i++){
    eventObj
    }
    """ % ('5')
```

it doesn't show error and works without any kind of problem, I thought that both are equivalent

The question is: **why happen that?**

Comment: You string has other `{` `}` in it. Format uses those as markers but `%` does not. So the other `{` `}` cause an error in format.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `format()` method, anything between `{` and `}` is treated as a parameter name or number that should be replaced with the corresponding argument.

Your string contains

```
{
    eventObj
    }
```

You get an error because there's no parameter that matches that name.

If you want to have literal `{` characters in a format string, you have to double them.

```
"""
    for(i=0;i<{0};i++){{
    eventObj
    }}
    """.format('5')
```

See [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

You don't get an error when you use `%` because it uses format operators beginning with `%`; `{` has no special meaning in the format string. In that case, you need to double the `%` character if it should be literal, but you don't have any literal `%` in your example.