# How to format json string with **dict in Python?

Tags: python, format

I want to format json string with **dict like normal string, but here somthing wrong with my code, how to do to meet my requirements?

**Here's my code:**

```
varDict = {"age": 18, "gender": "male"}
jsonStringVar = """
    {
        "persion":
            {
                "age": "{age}", 
                "gender": "{gender}"
            }
    }
"""

print(jsonStringVar.format(**varDict))
```

**And Exception as below:**

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'\n        "persion"'
  File "..\test_format.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(jsonStringVar.format(**varDict))
```

Comment: so many thanks, it works well.

Answer (score -1):

**Reference**: [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in python string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-python-string-and-also-use-fo)

**Solution:**

```
jsonStringVar = """
    {{
        "persion":
            {{
                "age": "{age}", 
                "gender": "{gender}"
            }}
    }}
"""
```