# Using python string format with placeholder

Tags: python, string, formatting

I know how to use string format in python

```
"name = {fname}".format(fname = "John")
```

The output is `name  = John`

But how can I use if I need to input `{}` inside the string that not belong to variable , for example

```
"{NOTVAR} name = {fname}".format(fname = "John")
```

I want to output will be `{NOTVAR} name  = John`

Comment: `"{{NOTVAR}} ..."` - [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466451/3001761).

Answer (score 1):

```
print("{{NOTVAR}} name = {fname}".format(fname="John"))
```

Output

```
{NOTVAR} name = John
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
"{{NOTVAR}} name = {fname}".format(fname = "John")
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to seperate it with a `+`.
Something like this:

```
print("{NOTVAR }" + "name = {fname}".format(fname = "John"))
```

> {NOTVAR} name  = John