# Getting Error in python SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, syntax

I am getting this error, i also need to pass variable in that string but it is giving this error for the following code:

```
   for i in range (0,4):
str =f'{"requests":[{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page="{i}"&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&facets=%5B%22brand_name%22%2C%22categories%22%2C%22sale_price%22%2C%22total_rating_average%22%2C%22express_delivery%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22categories%3ASmartphones%22%2C%22categories%3AMobile%20%26%20Tablets%22%5D%5D"},  {"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&hitsPerPage=1&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&clickAnalytics=false&facets=categories"}]}'
print(str)
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: agree. this code is not read-able. Better break up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe just just need to escape the curly brackets to make this work:

```
f'{{"requests":[{{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page="{i}"&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&facets=%5B%22brand_name%22%2C%22categories%22%2C%22sale_price%22%2C%22total_rating_average%22%2C%22express_delivery%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22categories%3ASmartphones%22%2C%22categories%3AMobile%20%26%20Tablets%22%5D%5D"}},  {{"indexName":"New_Telemart","params":"query=Mobiles&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&highlightPreTag=__ais-highlight__&highlightPostTag=__%2Fais-highlight__&hitsPerPage=1&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&analytics=false&clickAnalytics=false&facets=categories"}}]}}'
```

You can read the [f-string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information

Comment: for those who dont get the answer like me , read this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/10453703)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that the string is including dictionaries. As the standard dictionary and f-string uses `{}`, you are indeed going too deep. You will need to escape the brackets or remove the dictionary from the string to effectively utilize the f-string.