# python f-string how to use the {} character for a variable and as a string

Tags: python, string, f-string

```py
data = f'"{name}": ' + "{" + tmp + "},"
```

I have such a string, but I need so that I can use the string {} as for a variable or just as a string. What do I need to do for this?

Comment: Read the documentation for f-strings https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in a string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-and-also-use-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need double curly brackets

```
>>> print(f"{{}}")
{}
```