# Last curly brace kept being written on new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a .txt data like this :

```
215951.113,9121874.519,0
215963.471,9121913.567,0
216613.129,9115925.135,0
...
```

And i want to write it in this format :

```
    Point(1) = {219755.549,9129790.905,0} 
    Point(2) = {219754.857,9129793.278,0}
...
```

I made this kind of script :

```
f = open("D:\\TA\Input Data\Coastline\garpan_test.txt")
o = open("D:\\TA\Input Data\Coastline\garpan_test.geo","w+")
i = 1

for line in f :
    o.write(f"Point({i})= {{line}}")
    i=i+1
```

But instead it writes like this :

```
Point(1)= {219755.549,9129790.905,0
}Point(2)= {219754.857,9129793.278,0
}Point(3)= {219754.339,9129794.972,0
...
}Point(n)= {x,y}
```

I knew there is something wrong with the double curly brackets but i can't seem to find the same topic that explains it..
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-and-also-use-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the brackets

- `{{` and `}}` to print literal brackets, as your are in a f-string
- `{line}` to print `line` value

#### For the line construction

- there is a newline char at the end of each line, that you need to remove,
- add a newline char at the end to go next line
- add a tabulation at the beginning to get the expected output

#### For the code

- use `with` statement for files, it auto-closes them
- use `enumerate` to generate the `i` value

---

```
with open("garpan_test.txt") as f_in, open("garpan_test.geo", "w") as f_out:
    for i, line in enumerate(f_in, 1):
        f_out.write(f"\tPoint({i}) = {{{line.rstrip()}}}\n")

# OUT
Point(1) = {215951.113,9121874.519,0}
Point(2) = {215963.471,9121913.567,0}
Point(3) = {216613.129,9115925.135,0}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick! I'll learn about the `with` command and `enumerate` more after this

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

*I have used a list of strings to reproduce your problem.*

```
x = ['215951.113,9121874.519,0', '215963.471,9121913.567,0']

with open('garpan_test.geo', 'w') as f:
    for i,v in enumerate(x,1):
        f.write(f'Point({i}) = { {v} }\n')
```

Contents of the file

```
Point(1) = {'215951.113,9121874.519,0'}
Point(2) = {'215963.471,9121913.567,0'}
```

Comment: Use ```enumerate``` instead of```for i in range(len(x)):```