# .format() string, keep curly brackets if no match available

Tags: python

I try to format a string with curly brackets like this:

```
dct_mapper = dict(a=1)
s = '{key1: value2, key1: value2}; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}'
s.format(**dct_mapper)

Results in:
# KeyError: 'key1'

Expected:
# '{key1: value2, key1: value2}; attrib1=1; attrib2={b}'
```

An additional constrainment is that I need to use `.format_map()` later on the output again, this screws up solutions which use .format() because the out curly brackets will disappear.

I tried [defaultdict from the collections](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/) package and also into [.format_map()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format_map), then plaed around with regex trying to replace the [brackets with additional ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-and-also-use-format),  which feels less like a solution and more like a hack and also doesn't work if you have multiple repeating brackets in the string to begin with.

It is not a json string, because then I could have used the json library to map the values.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

I currently consider using a loop and `str.replace('{a}', 1)` but this feels clunky as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that this would be too fragile right? `s = '{{key1: value2, key1: value2}}; attrib1={a}; attrib2={{b}}'`

Comment: @JonSG unfortunately I think yes because I need to use .format() in multiple successions, but when using it the first time, the "outer shell" of curly brackets are gone. So I would have to re-create them again. But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: If values are provided for either or both of `key1` and `value2`, what does the result look like?

Comment: @JonSG, key1 and value2 are inside the dictionary which don't change. So (at least for my usecase) the output would not change. It would only change if a key like: 'key1: value2, key1: value2' is provided, which would be an edge case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you don't want to convert `{}` to `{{}}`, I suggest you using `Template` from `string`. Its interface allows you to custom the formatting options as I did below:

```py
from string import Template


class MyTemplate(Template):
    delimiter = ""


dct_mapper = dict(a=1)
s = MyTemplate('{key1: value2, key1: value2}; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}')
print(s.safe_substitute(**dct_mapper))
```

The output is, as you wanted:
`{key1: value2, key1: value2}; attrib1=1; attrib2={b}`

Explanation:
By default i `Template` you format strings using `$var` instead of `{var}` so I changed the pattern of the variable name (after the `$`) to be `${var}` and the delimiter itself to be "", so `{var}` is enough instead of `${var}`.

Moreover, templates have `safe_substitute` which allows you to format only few variables in the entire string and it doesn't raise an error for non-existing variable formats.

Also, `s.safe_substitute(**dct_mapper)` can be changed into `s.safe_substitute(dct_mapper)` if you prefer this over that.

Comment: This looks very good! I wasn't aware of Template. I have to play around a bit, but this is definetly much cleaner and solves the issue at hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your format string was invalid but assume you wanted to actually print the braces in that case.  Double the braces to print one literal brace.

You can subclass `dict` to just return the braced format key if the key isn't present.  This fills out `{a}` but leaves `{b}` alone:

```py
class MyDict(dict):

    # "magic" method called when a key is missing from the dict
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return f'{{{key}}}'

dct_mapper = MyDict(a=1)
s = '{{key1: value2, key1: value2}}; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}'
# Must use format_map.  format(**dct_mapper) doesn't work
print(s.format_map(dct_mapper))
```

Output:

```
{key1: value2, key1: value2}; attrib1=1; attrib2={b}
```

Comment: I'm starting with this as well and it works great for `a` and `b` but it will break down with the part that looks like a dictionary. Try `s.format_map(MyDict(a=1)).format_map(MyDict(b=2))` which is what I think they ultimately want to do.

Comment: @JonSG the part that looks like a dictionary is an invalid format specifier and breaks using `.format`.  If the OP wants do do something with that part they need to show an example and can't use `.format`.  @Jonathan `Template` looks promising, though, if a regex is formed to handle the wonky syntax.

Comment: I agree that the format specifier looks potentially broken and I asked them to clarify.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Hi thank you for the answer! I tried a similar approach as well. The problem with this is that I need to use .format_map() later again. So if you add the following two lines: `a = s.format_map(dct_mapper)`
`print(a.format_map(dct_mapper)` the code will also throw an exception.

Comment: @Andreas OK, but that case should be added to your question then.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, it was discuessed in the comments, but you are right. I will add it for future readers. Since your answer would work without the additional constrainment and because it also might help future readers I upvoted. Thanks for your help! Andreas

Comment: @Andreas Thanks.  Note with the syntax used in the "key1" format it is invalid, so you'd never be able to use .format as is.  The Template solution is good.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, yes I am aware of that. Unfortunately that is the kind of strings I have to work with. :/ Thanks for your help! Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dct_mapper = dict(a=1, b=2)
s = '{{key1: value2, key1: value2; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}}}'.format(**dct_mapper)
```

Output:
{key1: value2, key1: value2; attrib1=1; attrib2=2}

```
dct_mapper = dict(a=1, b=1)
s = '{{key1: value2, key1: value2; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}}}'.format(**dct_mapper)
```

Output:
{key1: value2, key1: value2; attrib1=1; attrib2=1}

But if you try to pass only 1 value, say for just "a", it will throw an error because format() is going to fill in the values given to all the {} in the string.

```
dct_mapper = dict(a=1)
s = '{{key1: value2, key1: value2; attrib1={a}; attrib2={b}}}'.format(**dct_mapper)
```

Output:
KeyError: 'b'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't help me to solve the problem, but future readers might find it helpful. Best wishes, Andreas