# Conditional formatting in strings

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this: '{}, {space}'.
Where I want to add/impute only the first value without touching the second ({space}) one.

But when i am doing like this:
'{}, {space}'.format(1), this is giving me error like: KeyError: 'space'.

Please help.

Comment: Can you pre-double the braces? `'{}, {{space}}'.format(1)` will return `'1, {space}'` (filling in the undoubled placeholder and dedoubling the braces for the other). Somewhat sillier (but not requiring modifying the format string) would be to do: `'{}, {space}'.format(1, space='{space}')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print curly-brace characters in a string while using .format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? Putting double brackets makes the {space} be ignored

```
print('{}, {{space}}'.format(1))
```

Output:

```
1, {space}
```