# How to load yaml string placeholders for python?

Tags: python, yaml, placeholder

I have a configuration file as `config.yaml`, that look like this

```yaml
misc.application_title: "ATT"

data_dir: "${APP_DIR}/aux_data"
```

I have a function in `app.py` where it loads the config from yaml file. My question is how to load `${APP_DIR}` as placeholder in the string.
I have to load string placeholders while loading yaml file itself.
Any leads will be appreciated .

Comment: Are you trying to fille the `APP_DIR` variable from inside the Python script? I am having a similar issue rn, trying to have a long python style string (with the {} inside of it) inside a file so that I can fill it from inside the program.

Comment: I found a solution for it, If you have trouble let me know, I can answer it here

Comment: I think I got it. I found another issue which was that I wanted to allow both using {} to print the curly braces and using {} to allow for the remplacement inside Python. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-print-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format seems to have solved it