# Replace consecutive delimiters in string with values from list

Tags: python

I have a string, for example:

```
s = "I ? am ? a ? string"
```

And I have a list equal in length to the number of `?` in the string:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3']
```

What is a pythonic way to return `s` with each consecutive `?` replaced with the values in `l`?, e.g.:

```
s_new = 'I 1 am 2 a 3 string'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### 2 Methods:

```
# Method 1
s = "I ? am ? a ? string"
l = ['1', '2', '3']

for i in l:
    s = s.replace('?', i, 1) 

print(s)
# Output: I 1 am 2 a 3 string
```

---

```
# Method 2
from functools import reduce
s = "I ? am ? a ? string"
l = ['1', '2', '3']

s_new = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace('?', y, 1), l, s)

print(s_new) 
# Output: I 1 am 2 a 3 string
```

Comment: I'd love to spend time to actually understand reduce and lambda expressions! Thanks for the 2 methods. I didn't realise replace allowed replacing a limited number of occurrences :)

Answer (score 3):

If the placeholders (not "delimiters") were `{}` rather than `?`, this would be exactly how the built-in `.format` method handles empty `{}` (along with a lot more power). So, we can simply replace the placeholders first, and then use that functionality:

```
>>> s = "I ? am ? a ? string"
>>> l = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> s.replace('?', '{}').format(*l)
'I 1 am 2 a 3 string'
```

Notice that `.format` expects each value as a separate argument, so we [use `*` to unpack the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847).

If the original string contains `{` or `}` which must be preserved, we can first [escape them by doubling them up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451):

```
>>> s = "I ? {am} ? a ? string"
>>> l = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> s.replace('?', '{}').format(*l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'am'
>>> s.replace('{', '{{').replace('}', '}}').replace('?', '{}').format(*l)
'I 1 {am} 2 a 3 string'
```