# Python pywinauto - Passes assignment of the repetition count to send_keys

Tags: python, key, send, pywinauto, f-string

I am using Python pywinauto to let the program automatically enter new line 20 times. I don't want to put 20 directly in send_keys() like: `send_keys('{ENTER 20}')`.

Instead, I want to pass an assignment of repetition count (ie: n=20) to send_keys(), like send_keys('{ENTER n}'). The whole program is:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
n=20
send_keys('{ENTER n}') -> This code not worked yet, still error here
```

Is there any solution for this? or how to pass argument by assignment to brackets inside the send_keys() in Python pywinauto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a general Python question not specific to pywinauto. For example, this way:

```
send_keys(f'{{ENTER {n}}}')
```

F-string requires un-escaping `{` or `}` by doubling it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/3648361

It's easy to check in any IDE with interactive interpreter:

```
>>> f'{{ENTER {n}}}'
'{ENTER 20}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f-string`s. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-escape-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format-or)

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
n=20
send_keys(f'{{ENTER {n}}}')
```