# a formatting problem when reading an html(CSS) with python when using .format()

Tags: python, html, format, smtplib

when i use .format() on a html string the Css in the html ruin the formatting.
what can i do to solve this problem ?

```
<style type='text/css'>
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .u-row {
    width: 600px !important;
  }
</style>
```

the error :

> ```
> </html>""".format(
>           ^^^^^^^
> ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape curly-brace ({}) characters in a string while using .format (or an f-string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-escape-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format-or)