# formatting string with parenthesis

Tags: python, automation, latex

I need to automatize the writing of a latex file. To do this, I need to format a string already containing "{" and "}" characters. To make an example, consider the string

```
a = "\begin{theorem} Consider the integral $$ \int_a^b {}dx  $$bla bla bla. \end{theorem}"
```

```
functions = ["x^2 -2", "e^{-x} + 7"]
```

```
f = functions[1]
```

```
a.format(f)
```

This code gives an error since there are already parenthesis "{}" filled with the word "theorem" in the beginning. If I erase "`\begin{theorem}`" and "`\end{theorem}`" the code works.

How can I format the string already containing the substring "`{something}`"?

I am using python 3.8, anaconda and spyder.

I could split the string in two, or three; or I could consider the word "theorem" as an argument of the format method, but can I do it directly? in other words which is the fastest solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape curly-brace ({}) characters in a string while using .format (or an f-string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-escape-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format-or)

Comment: Also, `\b` is interpreted as a backspace. You can fix this with double-backslash (`a = "\\begin... "`) or using a raw string literal (`a = r"\begin... "`)

Comment: Right. I think I wrote "\\begin..." but the editor changed it into "\begin..".

Answer (score 2):

Doubling the curly brackets (`{{` and `}}`) tells Python "these curly brackets aren't for formatting":

```
a = "\begin{{theorem}} Consider the integral $$ \int_a^b {}dx  $$bla bla bla. \end{{theorem}}"
```

This works with `a.format(f)` now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Following code

```
a = "\\begin{func1} Consider the integral $$ \int_a^b {func2}dx  $$bla bla bla. \end{func1}"
functions = ["x^2 -2", "e^{-x} + 7"]
f1 ,f2 = functions
a = a.format(func1=f1 ,func2=f2)
```

I have added a backslash for string "a" so that "b" at the beginning of the string will not be discarded. Guess it helps!

Comment: This doesn't work. OP intends to keep the parens, since this is LaTeX.