# When I'm using the .format to pass the dynamic values in json, I endedup getting KeyError: {\r\n PmtInfoByFileid(pmttypcde

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
start_date = os.environ.get('5678')
end_date = os.environ.get('1234')


query = json.dumps({
    "query": "query{\r\n PmtInfoByFileid(pmttypcde:\"A2A*\",pmtstatuscde:\"SCHEDULED\", txnstatusctgrytxt:\"DIY_ACTIVE_TRANSACTIONS\",\r\n startpmtexctndt:"{}",endpmtexctndt:"{}",pagesize:10){\r\n list{custlpid \r\n pmttypcde\r\n txntypcde\r\n pmtcrtndt\r\n pmtexctndt\r\n debtorinfotxt\r\n pmtstatuscde\r\n debtoraccntnbr\r\n btchcntrlsumval\r\n MnyMvmntCrdtTrnsfrTxnByPmtinfoid{\r\n pmtinstrctnid\r\n creditoraccntnbr\r\n creditortxt\r\n }\r\n }\r\n metadata{\r\n pageNumber\r\n limit\r\n totalPages\r\n totalRecords\r\n }\r\n }\r\n}".format(start_date, end_date),
    "variables": {}
})
```

I know it is considering all {} as placeholders, But I'm not sure how I can overcome of this error.

I wanted to pass the values dynamically

Comment: Here's the answer to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/22052558

Comment: This worked thank you x = " { Hello } %s"
print x%(42)