# Add contour labels with fmt and mathtext : pb with complex exponents

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

I'm trying to put labels on contour with some complex formatting and units string.

See the example :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Simple plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xx, yy = np.meshgrid( np.arange(20), np.arange(20) )
cc = ax.contour (xx, yy, xx+yy)

# Labelling the contours
## Not correct :only '-' is superscripted, not '3'
ax.clabel (cc, fmt='$\sigma=${:3.1f} $kg \cdot m^-3$'.format)

## Error : braces in math expression are interpreted as a format
ax.clabel (cc, fmt='{:3.1f} $kg \cdot m^{-3}$'.format)
```

How can I write the `fmt` string to have the correct printing? The braces in the math expression are interpreted as a format specifier, and generates an error. I can't escaped them.

Can I do that ? How ?

Thanks,

Olivier

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/3501128) you are almost there, just need to double the braces around the exponent: `fmt='{:3.1f} $kg \cdot m^{{-3}}$'.format`

Comment: OK, that's how I can 'escape' braces ! Thanks !