# How to escape a placeholder-looking variable in a string?

Tags: python, f-string

In Python I have the following code:

```py
# Create or overwrite the .github/workflows/build.yml file
with open(os.path.join(workflows_dir, 'build.yml'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(f"""\
... some YAML goes here. ...      
          client_id: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
          client_secret: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
""")
```

Python replaces:

```
client_id: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
client_secret: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
```

With:

```
client_id: ${ secrets.CLIENT_ID }
client_secret: ${ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }
```

The code is meant to replace some placeholders with variables and that's fine. In this case there is no such variable and this bit is actually not meant to be replaced because it's part of a Github workflow and Github will pass in these secrets.

I have also tried escaping like this:

```
client_id: ${{{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}}
client_secret: ${{{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You would need to double *all* of the curly braces - `${{{{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}}}` for example.  Or split the text into multiple string literals (which will be concatenated automatically) - use f-strings only for the parts that need substitutions, plain string literals for parts like this.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Please, feel free to post is as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape curly-brace ({}) characters in a string while using .format (or an f-string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-do-i-escape-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-while-using-format-or)