# Display latex table/tabular in Jupyter with latex cell magic

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

According to [this Rich Display System example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Display%20System.ipynb#LaTeX) the Jupyter notebook can display latex using the `%%latex` cell magic.

The example given using the `align` environment works fine on my system (`Notebook Server 3.2.0-8b0eef4`) but when I try and show a `tabular` or a `table`, the result is just nicely typesetting Latex code!

[image: Latex not working]

Is there some kind of preamble I need to add to make this work?

Comment: Try this very simple approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74358245/1162750

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Answer**

Jupyter builds on MathJax and cite "[MathJax doesn't implement tabular](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment)". The link also shows the recommended **array environment as tabular replacement**.

---

**Workaround:**

Latex can also be used in Markdown cells (Celltype Markdown instead of Code). You can select the left area besides the cell and press "m" key or via Cell>Cell-Type in top menu. Then you could use html for the table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\end{eqnarray}
        </td>
        <td>
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0
\end{eqnarray}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Markdown table two cells Latex Html mixed]

Markdown cells are rendered so you don't see the code that generates the rendered latex. Instead you just see the rendered version until you double click it.
Plus you have the option of [Markdown tables](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables)

Comment: Can I propose a change to this solution? The last part (in the update) is actually the answer I was looking for. The first part is a workaround, and could be included *after* the main solution.

Comment: Ok I changed title Update to Answer and moved it to top and rest as Workaround.