# Latex not rendering correctly on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, rendering

I am having some trouble with Latex on my Jupyter Notebook.

Whenever I try to use Latex expressiosn of the form \begin{} .. \end{} the code is not correctly rendered.

When I use inline expressions, like the $ whatever inside $ this, DOES work.

I have tried with the magic %%latex on code cells, as well as in markdown cells.

Here an example of what happens>

[image]

I read that many people have problems with this, but not concrete solution. Any ideas?? Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT ADD CODE

On a code cell with the %%latex magic

```
%%latex
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c   c   c | } \hline
        $k$ &   $x_1^k$  &   $x_2^k$  &    $x_3^k$   \\
         \hline
         0 & -0.30000000 & 0.60000000 &  0.70000000  \\
         1 &  0.47102965 & 0.04883157 & -0.53345964  \\
         2 &  0.49988691 & 0.00228830 & -0.52246185  \\
         3 &  0.49999976 & 0.00005380 & -0.52365600  \\
         4 &  0.50000000 & 0.00000307 & -0.52359743  \\
         5 &  0.50000000 & 0.00000007 & -0.52359885  \\
         6 &  0.50000000 & 0.00000000 & -0.52359877  \\
         7 &  0.50000000 & 0.00000000 & -0.52359878  \\
         \hline
\end{tabular}
```

On a markdown cell without the magic

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\end{itemize}
```

But the **following code renders as a matrix correctly**, so it's like tabular or itemize are broken?

```
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Var[X_1] & Cov[X_1,X_2] \\
Cov[X_1,X_2] & Var[X_2].
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Comment: Please, provide code example.

Comment: @RicardoRendich code added, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495336/8980634):

> Jupyter builds on MathJax and cite ["MathJax doesn't implement
> tabular". The link](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment) also shows the recommended array environment as
> tabular replacement.

I suggest to use [Markdown Cells](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html?highlight=table).

Comment: Thank you, i'll use this workaround with markdown for tables or lists.