# Jupyter notebook Markdown display error

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I've been using a Jupyter notebook to print output in Markdown format with the `IPython.display` module, following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/jupyter-notebook-output-in-markdown):

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
test_expression = '**blah** blah'
display(Markdown(test_expression))
```

When I execute that code block, I see the Markdown output as expected:

**blah** blah

But when I save, close and then reopen the notebook (without restarting the kernel), the same output is displayed incorrectly:

```
<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
```

Should I use a different command to display the Markdown to ensure that it's consistent?

Comment: No problem for me.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? I'm using Python 2 which might be part of the problem.

Comment: The issue is probably that you're opening the notebook as an untrusted notebook, see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#security-in-notebook-documents.